# How to get NSDictionary to return a subset given a search on 10 keys?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an NSDictionary object with 200 objects and 10 keys.
How do I return a subset and would it have to go to another NSDictionary or to an NSArray?

thanks

Comment: 200 objects and 10 keys?

Comment: Basically i have a database where there are 200 rows and 10 keys per row.

Comment: @Kristen Martinson: That would normally be modelled as an array of dictionaries, not a single dictionary. Do you mean that's what you have, or a dictionary with whose values are arrays of all the database entries for the key, or what?

Comment: @chuck, speed is sort of an issue here.  I can create an NSArray with NSStrings of 200 rows of data.  Then I can create a 2D array of my keys to index into it.  But it seems to me that "NS" has something to accomplish what I want faster than what I can do.  Maybe I am wrong with that assumption.

Comment: @Kristen Martinson: I'm just trying to figure out what data structure you're using. There might be "NS thing" to help you. But there's no such thing as "an NSDictionary … with 200 objects and 10 keys" — NSDictionary is a 1:1 mapping of keys to values. So I'm trying to figure out what you have. If it's an NSDictionary whose values are arrays, it'll take a custom algorithm. If it's an NSArray whose values are NSDictionaries, this is basically what NSPredicate was built for. If it's something totally different, maybe there's another way. There's no general data-structure-agnostic advice to give.

Comment: Agreed ... I think what @Kristen is saying is that she has 200 dictionary objects (all with the same key scheme) ...put those in an array (if they aren't already) and then use NSPredicate to get your subset quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects stored in `NSDictionary` are stored *by key*, so if you only have 10 keys, you can only have 10 objects. To illustrate:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dict setObject:@"test1" forKey:@"key"]; // dict["key"] = "test1"
[dict setObject:@"test2" forKey:@"key"]; // dict["key"] = "test2"
[dict setObject:@"test3" forKey:@"key"]; // dict["key"] = "test3"

NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"key"]); // will print "test3"

[dict release];
```

If you add something to the dictionary with the same key as an existing object, the old object is removed and the new one is added instead.

If you want a dictionary that stores 10 sets of objects per key, you would have to store `NSArray` objects in your dictionary:

```
[dict setObject:someArray forKey:@"someKey"];
```